# How to keep my bottomNavigationBar in subscreens?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a BottomNavigationBar that I use to switch between my main pages in my app, but on one of these screens I have a categories screen where if I select a category I do a Navigator.pushNamed for the selected category. But when I do this, my BottomNavigationBar does not remain because I go to a screen that is outside the children of my PageView. I would like to know how I can keep the BottomBar active.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CupertinoTabBar` instead of `BottomNavigationBar`.

From CupertinoTabBar api [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html):

> Tab changes typically trigger a switch between Navigators, each with
> its own navigation stack, per standard iOS design. This can be done by
> using CupertinoTabViews inside each tab builder in
> CupertinoTabScaffold.